# Is it possible to have two responsive photos merge via canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, html5-canvas, responsive-images

I've searched the web high and low.. I'm writing some code where I’m trying to merge two images from different URLs for a good presentation. One of the images is coming from Flickr.

Is it possible to merge two photos via html5 canvas into one element while keeping it responsive?

Example with canvas size parameters:
https://jsfiddle.net/esd3f4kt/

Example without canvas size parameters:
https://jsfiddle.net/n3x7wozc/

I've tried removing the size parameters on the canvas element and leaving the CSS code as is, but for some reason it doesn't paint the canvas in a "fluid" way.

Like this example:

https://codepen.io/html5andblog/pen/yOdBaw

Here is my code:

```
    function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
  }
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var sources = {
    image2: 'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4621/39922707792_c4eab8924c_b.jpg',
    image1: 'data:image/png;base64,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'
  };



  loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    ctx.drawImage(images.image1, 25, 5, 785, 589);
            ctx.drawImage(images.image2, 350, 150, 457/2.25, 645/2.25);

  });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? If you're trying to clip your photo to the oval, you can use `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';`.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make it so the images in the var sources are merged and behave like this example: https://codepen.io/html5andblog/pen/yOdBaw < that has no size parameter on it's canvas but yet it's able to adapt to the window size, I'd like to do that with two image sources in the same canvas.

This example: https://jsfiddle.net/esd3f4kt/ is limited because the approach is set with an 1000x1000 canvas size. 

If I remove the size parameters on the canvas and try to apply CSS to make the canvas responsive/fluid it doesn't work properly like this: https://jsfiddle.net/n3x7wozc/

Comment: If you don't set the canvas size with HTML, then you'll need to set it with JavaScript. You can either specify hard-coded dimensions, or wait for the `images[src].onload` function to execute and use dimensions based on the images that have been loaded.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll give it a try when I get home.